# BLE connection to mi band on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm working on the new app where I need to connect to mi band with BLE.
Any ideas how to connect mi band to mobile app on Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather old but for anyone passing by, here's the solution: https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue